# Can't install Grub to Windows HardDrive, Possibly corrupted BCD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair, grub-efi

I tried to install Ubuntu.
I have a separate hard-drive where I installed it. 
When I tried to install Grub to the other Windows Drive, it fails to install to it. I get an error fail to install.
I can still boot windows but can't boot Ubuntu. I have windows 10

I tried to rebuit BCD using EasyBCD but that didn't fix. I use to be able to install Ubuntu before without issues, but now I can't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your windows installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred Here is the link to the summary report. I have multiple hard-drives on this computer as you can see. Thank you http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/45B3gZQ39J/

Comment: Do not run Boot-Repair's autofix. It will install grub to all drives and you want to keep the Windows boot loader on the Windows drive. You want and need the Windows boot loader. Grub only boots working Windows or Windows that is not hibernated. In Windows turn off fast start up. Then in Ubuntu you can run `sudo update-grub` and it will add Windows to grub menu. But Windows updates will turn fast start back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply back. I was about to run Boot-Repair; I won't do that now. But I'm still not sure how to repair this, since I can't boot ubuntu after installing it. Grub isn't installed, and windows boots. Also where is Grub suppose to be installed since, I can't install it on the drive with Windows.

Comment: @oldfred I disable Fast Startup. I tried to reinstall Linux and grub. I get a fatal error. grub-install /dev/nvme1n1 failed.  I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: If UEFI you install to drive with ESP - efi system partition, if BIOS you install to drive with Ubuntu. With UEFI grub wants to use an ESP on first drive found. You do not install to a partition even though ESP is a partition, it automatically finds ESP. And not to a partition with BIOS boot systems. And I think only UEFI boot is supported with NVMe drives. Is nvme1n1 your first NVMe drive? First drive is usually nvme0n1. Your previous report showed two NVMe drives, but first was full drive LVM and looks like a BIOS/MBR install. You probably need UEFI/gpt.